Reference request on Niels Henrik Abel
The quote

"There are very few theorems in advanced analysis which have been demonstrated in a logically tenable manner. Everywhere one finds this miserable way of concluding from the special to the general  and it is  extremely  peculiar  that  such  a  procedure led to  so  few  of the  so-called  paradoxes."

has been attributed to Niels Henrik Abel. Where did he write that text, if at all?
Bonus question: if Abel wrote it, what may he have meant with "the so-called paradoxes"?

The answer by user14972 to the question Why is the notion of analytic function so important? at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2820378/276524 simplifies our work, as it attributes the quote to the book Niels Henrik Abel: Mathematician Extraordinary. The latter is available at  https://archive.org/details/nielshenrikabelm0000orey_j0s6/page/n5/mode/2up.

Sørensen, H. K. (2005). Exceptions and counterexamples: Understanding Abel's comment on Cauchy's Theorem. Historia Mathematica, 32(4), 453-480. Note also that discussion of "so-called exceptions" can also be found comments by Hilbert in 1922. See Corry, L. (2004). David Hilbert and the axiomatization of physics (1898-1918): From Grundlagen der Geometrie to Grundlagen der Physik (Vol. 10). Dordrecht: Kluwer. p. 422.

@GeorgEssl Thank you for that good article. It does not have the quote I ask about, it seems to me, but I think that it is an interesting reply to the bonus question.

Some here may, unlike me, be able to search the internet archive https://archive.org/details/nielshenrikabelm0000orey_j0s6/page/n5/mode/2up to identify the pagination for the quote in Øystein Ore's book Niels Henrik Abel: Mathematician Extraordinary.

The quote can be found on page. 461 of Sørensen, and it's sourced as a letter by Abel to Hansteen.

@GeorgEssl Please write up an answer for me to prefer, as your last observation, and the information involved with it, deserves to be on the record; especially as it includes Abel's original statement in the Norwegian-Danish language of his days in the text of the footnote on page 461.

The statement is in a letter from Abel to Hansteen, and has been subject to numerous historical discussions including the explanation of its context.
Contextual discussions can be found in:

Laubenbacher, R., & Pengelley, D. (1999). Mathematical expeditions:
Chronicles by the explorers. Springer. p. 105-106.

The relevant passage (with the letter of Abel omitted) is:

The missing understanding underlying various coalescing challenges was
"What is a limit?" i.e., what did it mean for a quantity that depends
on a variable to approach a limiting value as the variable itself
approaches a certain number. No conclusive answer had been proposed
yet, as we will discuss in the section on Leibniz's work.
This frustrating state of affairs was expressed by one of those who
contributed to bringing rigor to analysis, the Norwegian Niels Henrik
Abel (1802-1829), when he complained in an 1826 letter about
[.. quote from letter omitted ..]
Despite a few eighteenth-century attempts, it was Augustin-Louis
Cauchy (1789-1857) who finally substantially clarified the notion of
limit and resolved many foundational difficulties, allowing analysis
to develop further, by effectively obviating the necessity for
slippery and evasive infinitesimals.

Similar discussion can also be found in:

Jahnke, H. N. (ed.) (2003). A history of
analysis.
American Mathematical Society. p.176ff.

which states (again omitting the quoted letter):

6.4.3. Abel. A third mathematician who began the reform of the foundations of mathematics was Abel. In 1826 he wrote to his
professor, Hansteen:
[.. quote from letter omitted ..]
Earlier the same year he had been more specific in a letter to his
friend Holmboe:
On the whole divergent series is a devilry, and it is a shame that one
dares to base any demonstration on them. One can deduce whatever one
wants when one uses them, and they have done much harm and caused many
paradoxes. Can you think of anything more terrible than saying that
$$0 = 1 - 2n + 3n - 4n +  \text{etc.}$$
where $n$ is a positive integer. Risum teneatis amici. My eyes have
been opened in the most amazing way; indeed when you except the
simplest cases, e. g. the geometric series, there hardly exists in all
of mathematics a single infinite series the sum of which has been
determined in a rigorous way. In other words the most important part
of mathematics is without a foundation. Most of it is correct, that is
true, and that is very strange. I will try to find the reasons for
that. A highly interesting problem. - I do not think you could state
many theorems concerning infinite series against whose proof I could
not make well founded objections. Do so and I will answer. - Even the
binominal [sic] formula is not rigorously proved yet ... Taylor's
Theorem, the basis of all higher mathematics is equally badly founded.
I have only found one rigorous proof; it is by Cauchy in his Résumé
des leçons sur le calcul infinitésimal He shows that one has
$$\varphi(x+\alpha)=\varphi x+\alpha \varphi^{\prime}
> x+\frac{\alpha^2}{2} \varphi^{\prime \prime} x+\ldots$$
as long as the series is convergent (but one uses it without more ado
in all cases) [Abel had clearly not read the Resume carefully. Whether
he knew Cauchy's proof of the binomial theorem in the Cours d'analyse
is unclear] ... On the whole until now the theory of infinite series
is very badly founded. - One applies all operations to infinite series as though they were finite, but is that permissible? Hardly. - Where is it proved that one
gets the differential of an infinite series by differentiating each
term? - The same holds true of multiplication, division etc. of
infinite series .... (Abel 1902, 16-18)
Here Abel spotted many of the weaknesses in the arguments of his
contemporaries, including some (like termwise differentiation) that
had been overlooked by Gauss and Cauchy. In his letter to Hansteen he
announced that he would publish several small papers on these
questions in Crelle's Journal, but probably due to his early death he
only published one such paper (Abel 1826) dealing with the binomial
theorem. The most interesting part of this paper is the introduction
where he repeats several of the critical remarks from the letters
quoted above and the subsequent general theorems about series.

For further detail see the continuation in Jahnke as well as:

Sørensen, H. K. (2005). Exceptions and counterexamples: Understanding
Abel's comment on Cauchy's Theorem. Historia Mathematica, 32(4),
453-480. Letter cited on p. 461.

Incidentally the beginning of the letter to Holmboe is Abel's oft quoted statement about "divergent series being of the devil" paraphrased and translated from the original Norwegian in various ways.
The reference to so-called paradoxes would later be picked up by Hilbert in 1922, who in some sense warns against throwing out the baby with the bathwater when these "so-called paradoxes" emerge. From:

Corry, L. (2004). David Hilbert and the axiomatization of physics
(1898-1918): From Grundlagen der Geometrie to Grundlagen der Physik. Kluwer. p. 422.


Thus for instance, in a public lecture held in 1922 he said (emphasis is mine):
Every time that a new, fruitful method is invented in order to solve a
problem, in order to expand our knowledge, or in order to conquer new
provinces of science, there are, on the one hand, critical researchers
who distrust the novelty, and on the other hand, the courageous ones,
who before all others deplete the inexhaustible and productive
sources, swiftly achieve innovation and soon even gain weight over it,
so that they can silence the objections of the critics. This is the
period of the swift advancement of science. Often the best pioneers
are those who dare to advance deeper and are the first to arrive in
unsafe territory. Signs of the latter are unclearness and uncertainty
in the results obtained, to the point that even visible contradictions
and countersenses —the so-called paradoxes— arise. At this moment
reappear on the stage the critical tendencies that until now have
stood aside. They take possession of the paradoxes, uncover real
mistakes and thus attempt to incriminate the whole method and to
reject it. The danger exists that all the progress achieved will be
lost. The main task in such a situation is to hold this criticism back
(einzudämmen) and to look after a reformulation of the foundations of
the method, so that it remains safe from all its false applications
and, at the same time, that the ordinary results of the established
portions of mathematical knowledge can be incorporated into it.
(Hilbert 1922-23, 38-39)

The citation for Hilbert's statement is:

Hilbert (1922-23) Wissen und mathematisches Denken (HLN WS 1922-23,
annotated by W. Ackermann, edited by C.F. Bödinger – 1988).

This is certainly relevant even today, when work on divergent series continues, despite it's devilish nature, compare for instance:

Boyd, J. P. (1999). The devil's invention: asymptotic,
superasymptotic and hyperasymptotic series. Acta Applicandae
Mathematica, 56, 1-98.


@FrodeAlfsonBjørdal The earliest translation known to me is Ore (1974) p.114. thought there may well be earlier translations.

Letter to Professor Christoffer Hansteen (1826) in Oeuvres Complètes de N. H. Abel, mathematician, Nouvelle edition (1881) pp. 263-265 (this letter is absent in the original 1839 first edition):

Dans l'Analyse Supérieure bien peu de propositions sunt démontrées avec une riegueur définitive. Partout on trouve la malheureuse manière de conclure du spécial au general, et ce qu'il y a de merveilleux c'est qu'après un tel procédé on ne trouve que rarement ce qu'on appelle des paradoxes. Il est vraiment très-intéressant de rechercher la raisen de ceci. Cette raison, à mon avis il faut la voir dans ce que les fonctions dont s'est jusqu'ici occupée l'analyse, peuvent s'exprimer pour la plupart par des puissances. Quand il s'y en mele d'autres, ce qui, il est vrai, n'arrive pas souvent, on ne réussit plus guère, et pour peu qu'on tire de fausses conclusions, il en nait une infinité de propositions vicieuses qui se tiennent les unes les autres.


There are very few theorems in advanced analysis which have been demonstrated in a logically tenable manner. Everyone one finds this miserable way of concluding from the special to the general, and it is extremely peculiar that such a procedure has led to so few of the so-called paradoxes. It is really interesting to seek the cause.
To my mind, it lies in the fact that in analysis, one is largely occupied with functions which can be expressed by powers. As soon as other functions enter — this, however, is not often the case — then it does not work any more and a number of connected, incorrect theorems arise from the false conclusions.

